# How to change starting limit of a range of number

Tags: c++, image, math, pixel

I am currently stuck at this thing.

I have a range of `cdf's` from something like from 0.12 or 0.25 to 1. The lowerbound is dynamic depending on some counts. I want to change this to a range from 0 to 1. But I cannot think of anything right now.

Comment: I'm sorry, your question isn't clear enough for an answer.  What is clear, however, is that you're looking for a mathematical transformation, and nothing to do with programming, so this is off-topic for StackOverflow.  You might look into our sister site Mathematics.SE ... and rewriting your question to make it clear.  Some examples would help.

Comment: Given the 'cdf' and 'pixels' keywords, I'm guessing this is about normalization of an image histogram, for which the 'cumulative distribution function' values has been computed and for which one wishes to equalize the histogram over the full [0, 1] range.  Although rooted in simple math, this issue of image processing, implemented in C++, should have its place on SO.  Hadi should improve his question however ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have values [a, 1] and you want to project them on [0, 1] you can use the following formula:

```
 newVal = (oldVal - a) / (1.0 - a);
```